# Please clarify this expression for Expectation and variance

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

$
Var(X) = E((X -E(X))^2) =
\sum_x  p(x)(x-E(X))^2
$

How the last line came from it's previous line? can anyone kindly show me all of the steps? I know from common sense of probability theory that it does make sense, but i want to see mathematically how it came. I also know that $ Var(X) = E((X -E(X))^2) $

thanks in advance

Comment: The [expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition) of a given function $f$ of $x$ in a discrete space is pretty much by definition $\sum\limits_xp(x)f(x)$.

Comment: that's capital X How do you break that equation and get to the last line,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Expected Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition) of a given function $f$ of a random variable $x$ in a discrete space is pretty much by definition
$$
E(f(X))=\sum\limits_xp(x)f(x)
$$
In the example you give
$$
f(x)=(x-E(X))^2
$$